# Http call times out on client even though the server responded

Tags: c#, http, connection-timeout

I am making an Http call from a client application to the server which in some cases can take up to an hour to be processed and get a response back from the server.

I have increased the timeout of the HttpClient used to an hour so that it waits for the response from the server in these cases.

***The strange thing which I cannot explain is why sometimes the server application responds after ~30 minutes, but still the client waits the entire hour and then throws exception as if it never received a response and timed out instead.***

My question is in what scenario this can happen, the client not be aware of the fact that the server app responded and instead wait until it times out?

Edit: this is the code doing the Http call

```
var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
});

var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUri)
{
    Content = new StringContent(payload)
};

requestMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```

Comment: Long running requests like that, I wouldn't handle with a GET and monstrous timeout. I'd probably do it either via POST and poll or some sort of callback or webhook. Kind of like when you order at McDonald's and get a number that is called when your order is ready for pick-up.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods I completely agree. Unfortunately this is an app on which I can not change anything, so I am stuck with the timeout, and what do I do when I receive it... that's why I'm trying to reduce the cases when the client app on which I am owner behaves strange

Comment: Well, I'd actually file this as a bug with API manufacturer. But I fugure, this doesn't help you neither. So, can you share the code where you call that endpoint?

Comment: How do you know the server responds?

Comment: @shingo I have access to the server logs and it logged the 200 response for this specific request. It's a good point that even though it logged that it responded, it could have not sent the bytes back to the client which I can not verify

Comment: _" which I can not verify"_ - well actually you can. You need to use some Network inspection tool and filter for HTTP traffic. Then you can verify what's _actually_ been seen on the line. I don't think it's impossible that the server sent data, but the client network adapter dropped the packets for some reason.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods unfortunately it's more complex than that, because this happens quite rarely (once or twice a month) and the server app is hosted on a couple of servers having load balancer in front of them, which receive a few hundred thousand requests/day. Without updating the logging to log everything on the network side, I can not verify this...

Comment: Wait, so you test in production environment? ... uh oh ... I'd really urge you to set up a testing bench and reproduce the behavior. That way you don't need to tread on eggshells and even can do destructive testing without making the production system even worse.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods this has not been reproduced in any non prod envs yet, because we don't know why it happens. That's why in the question I want to get a few leads why this can happen

Comment: In this case, you need to look at what's _different_ between your test setup and prod. I guess it would be the load it is seeing, right? Maybe test has only one server without load balancing? Something like that?